# How to programmatically update a chart in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF application, where

- the user presses a button, thereafter
- a new data item is added to chart and
- the chart should be re-drawn.

What is the correct way to repaint the chart?

Currently, I have following code in the managed bean, which processes the button press event:

```
public void simulateYearButtonAction() 
{
    // Update other UI elements here

    this.updateChart();
}

private void updateBirthsChart() {
    final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final ChartBean bean =
            (ChartBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(
                    context, "#{chartBean}", ChartBean.class);
    final DataStore dataStore = (DataStore)this.simulationFacade;
    bean.addBirthsData(this.year-1, dataStore.getValue(DataStoreValueType.BIRTHS_LAST_YEAR));
}
```

In `ChartBean` I add a new data item to the chart series

```
public ChartBean() {  
    createCategoryModel();  
}  
private void createCategoryModel() {  
    categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();  

    birthsSeries = new ChartSeries();
    birthsSeries.setLabel("Рождения");

    birthsSeries.set(2012, 0);
    categoryModel.addSeries(birthsSeries);
}  

public void addBirthsData(final int aYear, final double aNumberOfBirths) {
    this.birthsSeries.set(aYear, aNumberOfBirths);
}
```

The page uses the `ChartBean` in this way:

```
<p:lineChart id="category" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}"
    legendPosition="e" title="Демографическая динамика" minX="2012" maxX="2112"
    style="height:300px;margin-top:20px" />
```

I don't know how to tell the chart that it should update now (and show the new data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is pressed a call to the backing bean method will be made which will rebuild your chart. After the action has finished by including `update="category"` your chart will be updated:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener=#{chartBean.refreshCategoryModel()}
                 update="category"/>
```

while in your backing bean:

```
public void refreshCategoryModel() {
    createCategoryModel();
}

private void createCategoryModel() {  
    categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();  

    birthsSeries = new ChartSeries();
    birthsSeries.setLabel("Рождения");

    birthsSeries.set(2012, 0);
    categoryModel.addSeries(birthsSeries);
}
```

The newly generated chart will probably depend on some dynamic values. Don't forget to `process` those components when you call your `<p:commandButton/>`.

You may find useful the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/12929296/407466.